# iOS Project Fails to Compile

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

When compiling iOS project developed with MvvmCross version 3.5.0, I get the following error:

Failed to resolve "Foundation.NSDate Foundation.NSDate::op_Explicit(System.DateTime)" reference from "Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is in the method:

public void Include(UIDatePicker date) in LinkerPleaseInclude class.
Trying to pass DateTime as NSDate.

Just comment out or remove following code :

```
public void Include(UIDatePicker date)
{
    date.Date = date.Date.AddSeconds(1);
    date.ValueChanged += (sender, args) => { date.Date=NSDate.DistantFuture; };
}
```

Also can be resolved by updating binary libraries to unified api.

You can get detailed information on

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/unified/

Answer (score 3):

You are likely using an *outdated* version of MvvmCross (or another 3rd party) that used an **old, preview** version of the **unified API**.

The error tells you an assembly (binary) is looking for a member that it cannot find, because it was removed: see section ["Converting DateTime to NSDate"](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/unified/).

Updating your dependencies (any assembly binaries) will solve this correctly, without *potentially* introducing other issue(s).